# Definition of Compact : Is "Sub"-cover Must be Proper?

Tags: compactness

Here's a given definition while I am reading the *Topology, Munkres.*

> **Definition**. A space $X$ is said to be compact if every open covering $A$ of $X$ contains a finite subcollection that also covers $X$.

Then my question here, when we check whether the open covering $A of X contains a finite sub collection that also covers X, that sub-collection must be **proper** or not?

I think it must be proper, or not that I haven't known that sub means equal to proper seeing the next example :

> The interval $(0, 1]$ is not compact; the open covering $A = \{(1/n, 1] | n ∈ Z^+\}$
>   contains no finite subcollection covering (0, 1].

Comment: No, but the requirement is only meaningful when the original cover is infinite.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah, I've just confused with finiteness with countability. thx

Comment: There's absolutely no need for the sub cover to be proper.  But if the original cover is infinite, a finite subcover must be proper.  If a set is such that it has no infinite open covers, it is compact.  But this is very moot.